# Determining Host Key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I determine the host key of the keyboard of my system ?

Comment: The host key? Is that the one next to the *any* key?

Comment: Jokes apart, suppose if i have to press Host Key + delete for a specific function, in that case what would be my host key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know what you are asking without context. However, putting my psychic debugging hat on, I'm guessing you are asking "When I run Microsoft Virtual Server and the documentation says 'Press the host key' what does it mean?"

[This page tells you more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720357%28WS.10%29.aspx) - the default is the right Alt key ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708368(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708368%28WS.10%29.aspx)).

In which case, the question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, it isn't a programming question. If you are asking something else - sorry, my psychic powers failed me :-)

Comment: Actually I am trying to run Android x86 on a netbook, and I have to press Alt + F7 to return back to the GUI from the console screen. But somehow, this combination, that works fine on a PC and laptop is not working on the netbook. i checked around and hence discovered this " host key + F7 " term.   Can u help me out in this ?

Comment: I've never used either of these systems, but a 10 second google found this web page: does that work for you? http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2691/virtualbox_change_host_key/